# Pass PendingIntent Request Code To Put Extra

Tags: android

I need to add a unique ID to each of my alarms which are being created inside of a PendingIntent.

```
 alarmIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, 0);
```

Currently the request code is being set to 0.

I want to be able to list the alarms inside of a `listview` then allow for the user to cancel the alarms times from the list. My logic is to use the unique ID for each alarm to cancel.

How do I set a unique id for each alarm created inside my pendingIntent?

This is the method I am using to `setAlarm()`

```
 public void setAlarm(Context context, Long affirmationTime){
        alarmManager = (AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, AlarmReceiver.class);
        alarmIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, 0);
        alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC, System.currentTimeMillis(), affirmationTime, alarmIntent);

        ComponentName receiver = new ComponentName(context, BootReceiver.class);
        PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();

        pm.setComponentEnabledSetting(receiver,
                PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_ENABLED,
                PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
    }
```

This is the method I am going to be using to `cancelAlarm()`

```
   public void cancelAlarm(Context context){
        // If the alarm has been set, cancel it.
        if (alarmManager != null) {
            alarmManager.cancel(alarmIntent);
        }
        // Disable {@code SampleBootReceiver} so that it doesn't automatically restart the
        // alarm when the device is rebooted.
        ComponentName receiver = new ComponentName(context, BootReceiver.class);
        PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();

        pm.setComponentEnabledSetting(receiver,
                PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED,
                PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
    }
```

Comment: The `requestCode` is whatever you make it. It's just a way to distinguish otherwise similar `PendingIntent`s.

Comment: Well I for sure didn't understand that. Is there no ID associated with the pending intents? How can I track them if they do not have an id? Or better yet how does the OS track them?

Comment: I mean I assume it just knows the memory location. Would it not make sense to use that as wouldnt it be unique

Comment: The `requestCode` is kinda the ID, at the app level, it's just that you assign it. The OS tracks them mainly by `Context`. If you request `PendingIntent`s with the same type and request code, and the `Intent`s match, they will be the same `PendingIntent`, no matter what you attach to the `Intent` for subsequent requests. The `requestCode` is a way to create a new `PendingIntent` that is otherwise the same as one the system is already holding.

Comment: That's the thing. `PendingIntent`s are reused to cut down on resource consumption.

Comment: Ok so to be clear. If I schedule 5 alarms in that function above. Which right now seem to have the request code 0. there will be 1 pendingintent holding 5 alarms? Would you mind showing me how I can track them with unique id? I see this question being asked a lot but without any example of how to get it done. I also saw someone else commenting on how it is not documented that well.

Comment: There will be 5 alarms all using the same `PendingIntent`. If you're trying to attach the `requestCode` so you can cancel the alarm, that's exactly how you should do it. Are you having a problem?

Comment: Gotcha. So would you mind showing me how to make those unique? I want to be able to list them in my listView then allow them to be cancelled.

Comment: Just use an incrementing counter to create new `requestCode`s. However you want to track them is up to you; e.g., `SharedPreferences`, or a database, or a file, etc.